# Make bot type something if a specific user types something random?

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I am new to c#.  I want my Discord bot to say something when a specific user types anything.  For example, if he types something the bot will respond "shut up".  The conversation would go as follows:

User: hello there, bot!
Bot: shut up

All I have been able to come up with is this:

```
                commands.CreateCommand("test")
                .AddCheck((command, user, channel) => user.Id == < user id >)
                .Do(async (e) =>
        {
                await e.User.SendMessage("shut up");
        });
```

This is not what I wanted it to do at all as this is a command that uses prefixchar = !test and also sends the message via private message.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any valid input for the specific user you have in mind? If not, then you could try a conditional user check when your async message received function gets called:

```html
        private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
        {
            var activity = await result as Activity;

            if (activity != null && activity.Text.ToLower().Contains(username))
            {
                await context.PostAsync($"Shut up {username}!");
            }                      

            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
        }
```

If the bot needs to reply with "Shut Up {username}!" for every single user, then you could tie the response to a ConversationUpdate in your messages controller:

```html
 private async Task<Activity> HandleSystemMessage(Activity message)
        {
            switch (message.Type)
            {
                case ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate: 
                    IConversationUpdateActivity update = message;
                    using (
                        var scope =
                            Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Conversation.Container,
                                message))
                    {
                        var client = scope.Resolve<IConnectorClient>();

                        if (!update.MembersAdded.Any()) return null;

                        foreach (var newMember in update.MembersAdded)
                        {
                            if (newMember.Id == message.Recipient.Id) continue;
                            await _configurationLibrary.MultiThreadLoadSettings();

                            var reply = message.CreateReply();
                            reply.Text = $"Shut up {username}";
                            await client.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return null;
        }
```

The switch statement is in case you want to scale up.

Comment: hi thanks for your comment! the bot should only be able to reply the shut up code to 1 specific user that types in the channel not everyone that types, like the code could detect either the users User ID or a specific role :)

Comment: You could use either of the examples for that, but from a clean code perspective, I would suggest using the first one and passing through the user.ID as username. Are you hard-coding the specific user ID that needs to get that reply or are you storing it in a DB somewhere?

Comment: i seem to get these 2 errors in the first code: error CS1061: 'IAwaitable<object>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'IAwaitable<object>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) and error CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'ToLower' and no extension method 'ToLower' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: How are you calling private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)? The errors suggest that you are passing in an object that has no toLower function (eg, not a string or byte) / not an actual object, and not using multithreading correctly when calling the method.

Comment: yea i probably done something wrong or insert it the wrong place, im pretty new to this so im not sure what im doing most of the time :P .. this is how i insert it https://pastebin.com/n4icxe0H

Comment: You're not actually calling the method anywhere, just declaring it. Also, I am not seeing anything in the sense of an HTTP post to kick off the bot, nor any dialog handling (they should be in separate files in any case). Also, consider separating your userID object into its own class, but that's a separate topic.

How familiar are you multi-threading? Maybe have a look at the Microsoft Bot Framework .NET template. There is a lot of setup that seems to be missing for your bot to work.

Comment: im not really familiar with anything tbh, my bot is working fine tho with all my commands, it can delete an x ammount of messages and kick users by command aswell

Comment: How are you kicking users out by command? I assume you are capturing the ID of them and kicking that selected user the moment somebody types a specific command into the bot? You can modify that message handling to say "Shut up". Also, you need logic to differentiate between kicking users out and messages that should be told to shut up.